# UICollectionView showing same image on multiple cells

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am facing a very strange problem. My UICollectionView is rendering the same image for multiple cells. I am loading images from external sources. Here is my code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell: TTElementViewCell? = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? TTElementViewCell
    cell?.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"dummyImage.png")
    let uniqueImageName = TTApplicationModel.sharedModel.cacheKey(fbUrl: crItem.profileImageUrl)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell?.load(cacheKey: uniqueImageName, url: crItem.profileImageUrl)
    }
    return cell!
}
```

Here is my load function inside a custom cell class named `TTElementViewcell` which extends `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
func load(cacheKey:String,url:String){
    let loader = TTAsyncImageLoader()
    let uniqueImageName = TTApplicationModel.sharedModel.cacheKey(fbUrl: url)
    if uniqueImageName != ""{
        loader.load(cacheKey: uniqueImageName, url: URL(string:url)!, completion: { (image:UIImage?) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageView.image = image!
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is the details of `TTAsyncImageLoader` class.

```
import UIKit
class TTAsyncImageLoader {
fileprivate let model = TTApplicationModel.sharedModel.imageCache

private func getDataFromUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _  response: URLResponse?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (data, response, error) in
        completion(data, response, error)
        }.resume()
}

func load(cacheKey:String, url:URL,completion:@escaping (_ success:UIImage?)->Void) {
    if let image = self.model.object(forKey: cacheKey as AnyObject) as? UIImage{
        completion(image)
        return
    }
    self.getDataFromUrl(url: url) { (imgData:Data?, response:URLResponse?, error:Error?) in
        if error == nil{
            self.model.setObject(UIImage(data: imgData!)!, forKey: cacheKey as AnyObject)
            completion(UIImage(data: imgData!)!)
        }else{
            print("TTAsyncImageLoader::load \(error!.localizedDescription) ")
        }
    }
}
}
```

The output is shown in the image:

[image]

Comment: The duplicated images, are they all dummyImage.png ?

Comment: @FangmingNing No.

Comment: Since you are using a custom image caching class, I suspect that it has some problem with image paths. To further validate, remove your image caching code and do only http calls. If that works, your local caching is not done correctly

Comment: Where is crItem.profileImageUrl defined?  Looks like that's referenced in your cellForItemAt IndexPath method but is defined outside that and doesn't change?

Comment: You can use SDWebImage framework for loading of images in CollectionView cells.